# Router saturates WAN traffic but none on LAN

Tags: networking, router

I have a DSL router (Vigor2860Vn-plus) which has two WAN interfaces (DSL + Ethernet via another DSL Router) and a LAN interface. I am using SNMP to keep track of the traffic on these interfaces.

Sometimes the router is overloaded and it seems like it is just sending traffic to the internet which is not originating from within my LAN.

**Any idea what could cause that?

Could this be some kind of amplification attack? 

Is it maybe a fault in the router?**

Here are some graphs of the last incident.

DSL upload is fully utilized.
[image: DSL upload is saturated]

WAN 2 is idle
[image: WAN 2 is idle]

LAN is used much less than the DSL. So the DSL traffic must originate somewhere from the router.
[image: LAN is also not doing much]

Comment: How confident are you that, for the logs and graphs, "LAN" also refers to on-board WIFI? If the snooping is done "downstream," Wifi might never hit a promiscuous hub etc etc.

Comment: Hmm, thats a good objection. The manual doesn't say anything about if wifi is accounted for. The wifi interface does not appear anywhere in SNMP. Guess I will have to try it out.